# Write a dictionary into single row in csv

Tags: python-3.x

```
my_dict1 = {1:'apple',2:'orange', 3:'banana'}
my_dict2= {1:'cat', 2:'mouse'}
```

I would like to add both dictionary into csv, so csv should look like

```
col1  col2     col3   col4    col5   col6
 1   | apple |  2  | orange |  3  | banana 
 1   | cat   |  2  | mouse
```

Answer (score 0):

Build your rows like this:

```
row = ",".join([f"{k},{v}" for k, v in my_dict1.items()])
```

Answer (score 0):

you can trying this:

```
import csv
from functools import reduce
my_dict1 = {1:'apple',2:'orange', 3:'banana'}
with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    writer.writerow(list(reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, my_dict1.items())))
```

Comment: You might want to include explanations.